# unable to scroll cardview containing list views

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I have a layout which contains 3 cardviews inside it. One of them has static content and a fixed size while the other three contains dynamic content being loaded from a list view.

I am getting scrollable content inside the 3 cardviews ,but instead i want the list views to fill_parent inside the cardviews and the cardviews should scroll instead. Here's my code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.animo.gita.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commiter_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        tools:text="animo93" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/days"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="4 days ago" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commit_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Added File Fragment" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commit_desc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        tools:text="33 changed files with 506 additions and 42 deletions." />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="FILES CHANGED"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/changed_files_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="FILES ADDED"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/added_files_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="FILES RENAMED"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/renamed_files_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can anyone please provide me an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `CardView's` container `LinearLayout` with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` for nested scrolling.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.animo.gita.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commiter_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        tools:text="animo93" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/days"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="4 days ago" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commit_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Added File Fragment" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commit_desc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        tools:text="33 changed files with 506 additions and 42 deletions." />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="FILES CHANGED"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/changed_files_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="FILES ADDED"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/added_files_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="FILES RENAMED"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/renamed_files_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It's giving "ScrollView can host only one direct child " Error

Comment: I forgot to add `LinearLayout` inside `NestedScrollView`. ScrollView must have only one direct child.

Comment: I also tried that , but this time the card views just wrapped content and did not fill the screen